# DARTlang get client IP

Tags: websocket, dart

My server code starting like this, I want to get the client IP, whenever connect and whenever disconnect.

```dart
List<WebSocket> connections;

void main() {
     connections = new List<WebSocket>();

     HttpServer.bind(HOST, PORT).then((HttpServer server) {
        print('Server listening on port ${PORT}.');
        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
          if (WebSocketTransformer.isUpgradeRequest(request)) {
             WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then(handleWS); 
           } else gotMSG(request);        
       });
     }); 
 }

 handleWS(WebSocket ws){

     connections.add(ws);
     print('Client connected, there are now ${connections.length} client(s) connected.');
     ws.listen((String message) {
        for (WebSocket connection in connections) {
        connection.add(message);
      }
    },
    onDone: () {
       connections.remove(ws);
       print('Client disconnected, there are now ${connections.length} client(s) connected.');
    });
 }
```

any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any way to get the IP from a `WebSocket`, but you could get it from the `HttpRequest` and pass it in from there; something like this (note: I'm unable to run this, so you might need to tweak to make it work):

```dart
// in main()...
// Pass client IP into handleWS, which now returns the function
webSocketTransformer.upgrade(request)
  .then(handleWS(request.connectionInfo.remoteAddress)); 



 // handleWS now takes the IP, and then returns the original function,
 // which now has clientAddress in scope. 
 handleWS(InternetAddress clientAddress) {
   return (WebSocket ws) {
     connections.add(ws);
     print('Client $clientAddress connected, there are now ${connections.length} client(s) connected.');
     ws.listen(
       (String message) {
         for (WebSocket connection in connections) {
           connection.add(message);
         }
      },
      onDone: () {
        connections.remove(ws);
        print('Client $clientAddress disconnected, there are now ${connections.length} client(s) connected.');
      }
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it. Note the use of `.connectionInfo`

```
HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4,8090).then((HttpServer server) {
  print("HttpServer listening at ${server.address}:${server.port}...");
  server.serverHeader = "EventDashboard Socket server by Jan D.";
  server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
    if (WebSocketTransformer.isUpgradeRequest(request)) {
      print(request.connectionInfo.remoteAddress);
      WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request).then(handleWebSocket);
    }
    else {
      print("Regular ${request.method} request for: ${request.uri.path}");
      request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
      request.response.reasonPhrase = "WebSocket connections only";
      request.response.close();
    }
  });
```